# Issue in getting all public data of a user with valid access token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, explorer, facebook-access-token

I am facing same issue problem in getting all public data of a user with valid access token. When making a call with graph API Explorer with same permissions, getting All public data available of the user queried for. But while trying to access same with a Graph API application with access token generated with exactly same permissions, getting only few basic fields independent of whatever data is publically available. While Debug, it seems access token generated with graph API explorer is able to fetch more data from facebook servers, while general access token generated with Oauth doesnt. With this access token I am able to get relevent data of user generated access token, but not publically available information of other users.